# parallax.js not working correctly

Tags: javascript, parallax

I am trying to put together parallax section scrolling using parallax.js. I cannot seem to get the sections to work correctly. I am following the tutorial they have at http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ but for some reason my code is not working correctly. Not sure if i'm missing something or if the code it not responding as it should. Can someone shed some light on this issue? my test code is listed at http://gynxprinting.com/test/

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a Jquery plugin you'll also need to load Jquery,

try adding

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: also switch `class="parallax-container"` to `class="parallax-window"`

Comment: I actually left out the tag to set html { height: 100%; } and that fixed it right up.

Comment: Thank you user3262111, I spent almost a whole day trying to figure it out. I added the html height to the CSS and it worked. Wow. I thought it was my apache configuration or there was a javascript issue or something since I had to set up my dev environment on my mac again (was using vagrant before)